# How can I perform concatenation on numbers in batch?

Tags: string, batch-file, numbers, concatenation

For example, I have the numbers 5, 3, 8, 2, 7, 4 and 9 which I got from operations such as `2+2`, `7-2` and `3*3`, etc... They are all stored in variables. I want to know if there is a way I can dynamically perform concatenation in batch files to get a result such as the string "5382749". With up to 6 digits, I can do `%v1%%v2%%v3%`... but after that I get an "Invalid number. Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision." error. What I am trying to do is echo a certain number of concatenated digits to the command line.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is easy.
A small sample

```
set /a num1=2+2
set /a num2=7-2
set /a num3=4
set concat=%num1%%num2%%num3%
echo %concat%
```

Comment: This should work with ~8190 digits as a string, but you can only calculate with 10 digits (2.147.483.646)

Comment: I know, I tested it and it solved my problems. Thanks very much!